# Can low PSU wattage limit resolution?

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, power-supply, resolution

I am setting up a workstation to display onto a 4K screen.

There was an existing eMachine EL-1352 sitting around so I purchased a [geForce 720 low profile video card](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-720/specifications) which can do 4K res according to specs. I have this set-up using the HDMI port and HDMI 2.0 cable.

I can not get it to go beyond 1080p resolution but otherwise it displays totally fine. The only oddity with the set-up is that the video card recommends 300 watt PSU and this eMachine has 220 watt.

I have never heard of PSU limiting resolution however and I couldn't find anyone else complaining about limited resolution with the geForce 720 so I verified it was not a problem with the monitor by hooking this eMachine into another 4K display (same monitor model) that was already set-up and running 4K fine, but it wouldn't go beyond 1080p on that either.

The resolution settings on the computer will not give me an option to go beyond 1080p. Is it reasonable to think that the wattage problem is causing this?

In other words, should I go buy a 300 watt PSU for this thing or try to find something else wrong?

Maybe Windows XP doesn't support 4K? (my operational 4K display is running on Windows 7 OS)

I am working with:

- eMachine EL-1352 PC
- Seiki 39" 4K monitor
- geForce 720 video card
- HDMI 2.0 connections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PSU would cause it crash, but not impose a resolution limit.

I *suspect* your issue is the interface. VGA doesnt support 4k. DVI-D supports 2560x1440, HDMI 1.4 supports 2560x1440. The max resolution is the max res the GPU can support, the card requires dual links to the display to actually implement that. A HDMI2.0(newish) interface or DisplayPort can manage 4k.

Update:
From the Nvidia spec sheet:
* - 3840x2160 at 30Hz or 4096x2160 at 24Hz supported over HDMI. 3840x2160 at 60Hz supported over DisplayPort

http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-730/specifications

Comment: Thanks, I clarified the question because I am not using VGA. Additionally, the operational 4K display is using a single HDMI 2.0 running out of a geForce 730. By `dual links` do you mean I would need to plug the monitor into the DVI port _and_ the HDMI port both?

Comment: I've edited my answer, it can push it over HDMI, only DP, and only up to pseudo-4K not true 4k.

Comment: OK decided to not mess around with the PSU and the geForce 720 on my old eMachine based on this. I am going to stick to what already works and am buying a new pc and another geForce 730 (instead of the low profile 720 I got for the eMachine)

Comment: Dual-link means using a dual-link DVI cable, nothing to do with the other ports. It basically has twice as many pins (rougly) and carry two signals.

Comment: @Geronimo I think you need a better core than a 730.

Comment: I have an existing 730 (DDR5 version) that seems to be supporting 4K on a Seiki 39" (probably not true 4K but visually good enough for my purposes). I think where I messed up on the 720 was getting it in a DDR3 version (necessary to fit inside of a tiny eMachine box). @qasdfdsaq thanks for that.

Comment: @Geronimo Yeah you're grand I suspect then "4K Ultra HD from Seiki. With over 8 million individual pixels (3,840 x 2,160)"

Answer (score 0):

No; if your power supply can not handle the load, it simply shuts down.

Comment: This doesn't appear to add anything not already present in other answers.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton, the other answer says crash.  It doesn't crash, it just immediately powers off.

Comment: Crappy power supplies may well crash rather than shut down, even crappier power supplies can catch fire, then crash, then shut down.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq, maybe if you buy parts from some fly by night Chinese company that isn't worried about getting sued.  Anything from a brand that is _at all_ known won't do that.  Certainly not if they are UL listed, which is something you should look for in any electrical device.

Comment: Fujitsu Siemens isn't a "fly by night Chinese company". Siemens is German for one.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq, then their equipment will definitely not malfunction like that.

Comment: Yes it will. Everyone's equipment can and does malfunction.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq, no, because they design them to fail safely.  For older analog power supplies this meant having a fuse to blow before other things smoke.  For modern SMPS, it means it has a digital shut off when it detects over-current.  These sorts of safety features ( and much, much more ) are required by UL for all electrical devices, and in particular, the ATX standard requires them of ATX compatible power supplies.

Comment: Keep living in your dream world. Meanwhile people who have power supplies, batteries, and everything else that catch fire know full well you're wrong. Nobody cares what is required for UL when UL isn't required for anything.

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the point. I'm not saying these devices aren't designed to be safe. I'm saying failsafes can and do fail. Even in commercial jetliners, which are designed to a far higher standard than consumer power supplies, with triple redundant failsafe everything, can and do still fail. If having a name-brand on it is the only thing required for safety we wouldn't have Sony, Apple and Samsung batteries or Boeing jetliners blowing up because of technical or design failures. In the real world if PSUs were 100% safe we wouldn't need fuses or RCDs on the sockets.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq, I think *you* missed the point.  We're not talking about the one in a million, when the stars align just right and everything goes to hell problem... we're talking about the expected, normal behavior, which is that it simply shuts down rather than do anything like limit the resolution of your display.

Comment: If you're not talking about the same thing as me why bother replying to my comment at all, asserting that I'm missing my own point?